# Emoji symbol at left and emoji box also left side using plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, emoji

I am developing a new chatbot. in this, I am created input just like WhatsApp web. I face trouble to take the emoji symbol before the input tag.

My code is below

```js
$("#mytext").emojioneArea({
  pickerPosition: "bottom"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojionearea/3.4.1/emojionearea.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojionearea/3.4.1/emojionearea.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="mytext" />
</div>
```

I am trying to build this type of input

[image: input style]

and emoji panel opens above from smiley

[image: emoji also open left side]

Comment: Use pseudo code. input::before{ content: ""; background-image: emoji.png;  .... }

Comment: please show me briefly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the pseudo-code but if you're going off of javascript in which html is created, then you can do this:

```
.emojionearea{
  margin-left: 25px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.emojionearea-button{
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d9gsvjrq/

Comment: Nice but Emoji box is in right. I am trying to get this box  open in left side. Above smiley